# Если человек уже есть в бд машина состояний не срабатывает а сразу выдает кнопки

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Написал код на aiogram, мне нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку старт если айди пользователя уже есть в базе машина состояний не сработала а сразу выдала меню.
Сейчас бд через sqlite3 при каждом нажатии на кнопку старт срабатывает машина состояний

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram import Dispatcher, executor, types
from markup import mainMenu, Menustock
import os
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from data_base import barber_db







class reg(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    age = State()
    phone = State()
    userid = State()

storage = MemoryStorage()






HELP_COMMAND = """
/help - спиоск комманд
/start - начать работу с ботом
"""



# бот - сервер который будет взаимодействовать с АПИ телеграм
bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)



@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def help_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(text=HELP_COMMAND)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Привет мы еще не знакомы ?,\nКак тебя зовут')
    await reg.name.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=reg.name)
async def state1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await reg.next()
    await message.reply(f' Сколько тебе лет')


@dp.message_handler(state=reg.age)
async def state2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['age'] = message.text
    await reg.next()
    await message.reply(f'Тебе осталось только написать свой номер =)')


@dp.message_handler(state=reg.phone)
async def state3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['phone'] = message.text
    await barber_db.sql_add_command(state)
    await state.finish()
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                         text="Добро пожаловать",
                         parse_mode="HTML",
                         reply_markup=mainMenu)


@dp.message_handler() #Кнопки
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == '✄ Услуги и цены':
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, open(r'C:\Users\s-jay\Desktop\servise.jpg','rb'))
    elif message.text == '★ Команда':
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, open(r'C:\Users\s-jay\Desktop\comand.jpg','rb'))
    elif message.text == '⇅ Проложить маршрут':
        await bot.send_location(message.from_user.id, latitude=(43.319896),longitude=(76.914308))
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, open(r'C:\Users\s-jay\Desktop\photo_2022-09-28_18-01-10.jpg', 'rb'))
    elif message.text == "↯ Акции":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Выберите акцию', reply_markup=Menustock)
    elif message.text == "Назад":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Главное меню', reply_markup=mainMenu)




async  def on_startup(_):
    print('Бот вышел в онлайн')
    barber_db.sql_start()

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: Ну так сделайте в старте проверку, вытащите юзера из БД по юзер_айди и если он есть то `return`

Comment: то есть такое возможно да реализовать если сделать проверку через if то нижние хендлеры не запросят инфу по новой ?

Comment: Абсолютно не поняли что вы сейчас написали

Comment: В общем идея в том что бы машина состояний постоянно не запрашивала одни и те же данные вот не могу понять как это сделать